# NLTK stopwords returns error "LazyCorpusLoader is not callable"

Tags: python, nltk, typeerror, stop-words

I am trying to write a python program to remove stopword from a sentence using nltk package

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
chachedWords = stopwords.words('english')
```

the following gives `TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not callable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")
chachedWords = stopwords.words('english')
```

Comment: Thanks. Just found the import error. Trying the download.